# Read sql file into dataframe

Tags: python, mysql, sql, pandas

I've looked through past posts but I'm struggling to figure out what to use for a connection object. I'm trying to just get a quick solution here that doesn't require me to spend days learning SQL, since I'm not interested in learning all that. I have a .sql file, and I simply want to get the data in it into a pandas DataFrame. Here's an example of the .sql file:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `championship`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `championship` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `year` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `position` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `_driver` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `points` float NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1271 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

TRUNCATE TABLE `championship`;

INSERT INTO `championship` VALUES(1, 1950, 1, 15, 30);
...[bunch of entries]...
INSERT INTO `championship` VALUES(1390, 2020, 23, 1191, 0);


ALTER TABLE `championship`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`), ADD KEY `_driver` (`_driver`);

ALTER TABLE `championship`
MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=1391;

ALTER TABLE `championship`
ADD CONSTRAINT `championship_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`_driver`) REFERENCES `drivers` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

All I have is this saved as "championship.sql", so when it comes to creating engines and connections I have no idea what to put for like username, password, ports, etc. It seems pandas requires this kind of connection to read the file.

Comment: You can't use `pandas` to extract data from a sql script.  You need to run the script against a database server, to populate a database, then run a query against that database *(such as `SELECT * FROM championship`)*, then pass the results to pandas to create a dataframe.  Try reading here...  https://pythontic.com/pandas/serialization/mysql

Comment: Or, use a text editor to manually change that into a csv file with only the data, then you can use pandas to parse the csv file.  You could even parse it programmatically, but then you have to be ***very*** careful about how the file is structured, so as to avoid false assumptions about how to process that file.  Neither of those options involve `pandas` being able to magically extract data from a script.